# GLError within GlEndList() within classic greas.py example

Tags: opengl, fedora, pyopengl

Attempting to run [this gl gear code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~mcfletch/pyopengl-demo/trunk/view/head:/PyOpenGL-Demo/GLUT/gears.py) on a virtual machine results in the following stack trace:

```
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x92e18b0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0xd4 returned 1 visuals
OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x92e18b0
OpenGL Warning: Retry with 0xd4 returned 1 visuals
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gears.py", line 264, in <module>
    init()
  File "gears.py", line 234, in init
    glEndList()
  File "errorchecker.pyx", line 50, in OpenGL_accelerate.errorchecker._ErrorChecker.glCheckError (src/errorchecker.c:1050)
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError(
    err = 1280,
    description = 'invalid enumerant',
    baseOperation = glEndList,
    cArguments = ()
)
```

But the same code works fine on my desktop -- both machines run the same version of pyOpenGL and all packages install should be the same.  However, the underlying OS is Fedora 12 on the virtual machine and Fedora 16 on the desktop.

What could cause this?

As requested in answer:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Humper
OpenGL renderer string: Chromium
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Chromium 1.9
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20 NVIDIA via Cg compiler
OpenGL extensions:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you're running a version of OpenGL less than 1.2. Check the version of OpenGL you're running.

Comment: If that helps, `OpenGL.__version__ = '3.0.2a5'`, mesa lib is 7.7-4, and `/usr/lib/libGL.so.1.2` is the version that I see in `/usr/lib`.

Comment: Could you please post the output of "glxinfo | grep OpenGL" ?

Comment: Did the glxinfo give you any clue?

Comment: From what I can tell, this is a problem with your OpenGL implementation. I tried it on a few of my Linux installs (Debian, Ubuntu) and the code runs great.

Comment: Probably something to do with the virtual machine graphical drivers.  Ah well, thank you for your help.